# Binding isn't working for ListBox while using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a simple UserControl with a DropDown showing versions like V14, V15 etc.

I have another ListBox whose ItemSource is binded to a property in the ViewModel which depend upon the SelectedValue of the Version DropDown.

ViewModel Looks like this:

```
 class MultiSelectEnvironmentContextControlViewModel: ViewModelBase
    {
        private string selectedVersion;
        private DomainFacade domainFacade;
        private ObservableCollection<string> environments= new ObservableCollection<string>(); 

        public MultiSelectEnvironmentContextControlViewModel()
        {
            domainFacade = ((App) Application.Current).DomainFacade;

        }
        public IEnumerable<string> EnvironmentVersions
        {
            get
            {
                return (domainFacade.GetEnvironmentVersions().Select(v => "Version " + v));
            }
        }    

        public string SelectedVersion
        {
            get { return selectedVersion; }
            set
            {
                selectedVersion = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Environments");
            }
        }


                 public ObservableCollection<string> Environments
    {
        get
        {
            environments = (ObservableCollection<string>)(domainFacade.GetEnvironments(SelectedVersion));
            return environments;
        }
    }

    }
```

I am keeping track of the SelectedVersion in a property which raises PropertyChanged on Environments so that whenever SeelectedVersion changes, the Environments should update the UI.

Issue I am facing is, ehn I run the application, I see the versions being populated, but there is nothing in the ListBox.

I am setting the DataContext of the UserControl to the ViewModel in the constructor of the UserControl.

Here is how my Control.cs file looks like:

```
 public partial class MultiSelectEnvironmentContextControl : UserControl
    {            
        private static MultiSelectEnvironmentContextControlViewModel dataContext = new MultiSelectEnvironmentContextControlViewModel();

        public MultiSelectEnvironmentContextControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = dataContext;
           dataContext.SelectedVersion = (string)this.ComboBoxVersions.SelectedItem;

        }              

        private void ComboBoxVersions_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
          dataContext.SelectedVersion = ((ComboBox) sender).SelectedValue.ToString();              
        }
}
```

Here is the XAML:

```
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="ComboBoxVersions" SelectedIndex="0" Margin="10" SelectionChanged="ComboBoxVersions_OnSelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding EnvironmentVersions}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10">
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,10,0">Tests to be run for:</TextBlock>
        <ComboBox  Name="ComboBoxFileTypeSelector" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableValidationTypes}" DisplayMemberPath="Key" SelectedValuePath="Value" SelectedIndex="0">
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>

    <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxEnvironments" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Height="300" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{Binding Environments}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="800" >
                </WrapPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxEnvironment" Content="{Binding}" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Margin="5">
                </CheckBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you post your XAML for the list box so that we can see how your binding the front end up

Comment: The issue might be in how you declare the datacontext code-behind. The point of using MVVM is to not write code in UI elements .cs files. You should declare the datacontext and the bindings in XAML instead.

Comment: It's a very bad idea to return a new `ObservableCollection<string>` from the `Environments` property getter. You would work on multiple different instances of the collection if the property is called multiple times.

Comment: What? That still creates a new instance on each call.

Comment: Have you tried to add breakpoint to Environments property getter, debug it and see if it is hit when the listbox should be populated?

Whats written in output window in VS while debugging you app (Menu->Debug->Windows->Output)?

Comment: I have a strong dislike for getters that do anything other than return a value - yours currently have method calls and casts. Getters should be nigh-on invincible and incapable of failure. They should provide an instantaneous read of properties which are set elsewhere in code. Per @Clemens comment, it's highly plausible that returning a new ObservableCollection (rather than returning one instantiated in the ViewModel constructor and henceforth manipulated using Add/Clear/Remove) is upsetting your bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is because `SelectedVersion` has values like "Version 1", "Version 2", etc, but your method `DomainFacade.GetEnvironments(string version)` expects values like "1", "2" etc.

I would write your viewmodel like this:

```
public class MultiSelectEnvironmentContextControlViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string selectedVersion;
    private DomainFacade domainFacade;
    private IEnumerable<string> environments;

    public MultiSelectEnvironmentContextControlViewModel()
    {
        domainFacade = ((App)Application.Current).DomainFacade;
        EnvironmentVersions = domainFacade.GetEnvironmentVersions();
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> EnvironmentVersions { get; private set; }

    public string SelectedVersion
    {
        get { return selectedVersion; }
        set
        {
            selectedVersion = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedVersion");
            Environments = domainFacade.GetEnvironments(SelectedVersion);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Environments
    {
        get { return environments; }
        set
        {
            environments = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Environments");
        }
    }
}
```

}

and applied to formatting of environment versions in view:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedVersion}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding EnvironmentVersions}"
          ItemStringFormat="Version: {0}" />
```